# debug assertion failure during domodal

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, cdialog

I have just started working on `CDialog` classes. When I try to execute the following code, I am getting debug assertion failure.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include <afxwin.h>
#include "dialog.h"
#include <Windows.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    dialog dial(NULL);
    dial.DoModal();
    return 0;
}
```

I have created a dialog resource and `CDialogEx` class named dialog. The error I am getting is 
"Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: ...pp_projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe
File: f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\include\afxwin1.inl
Line: 24"
Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: Why do you try to implement a modal UI, only to pass in `NULL` as the owner window. What effect did you expect the call of `DoModal` to have?

Comment: @IInspectable In the MSDN page it is mentioned that NULL should be passed to set the dialog object's parent window to the main application window. So i kept it like that. But I really cant understand what they mean..

Comment: What *main application window* are you talking about? You have none. And please do provide your `dialog` implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your project name suggests that you have created a Win32 Console Application project and added the MFC stuff. What you need to create is a MFC Application project.

MFC can also be used in a console application, but then you would not show dialogs and you would need to initialize MFC first.

Comment: yep, i forgot to initialize MFC. i need to include AfxWinInit in my code. thank you.